# Permissions on a hidden share

Tags: c#

Is there a way in c# to check whether a given user (in particular a sqlserver service account) has permissions on a hidden share?

I have tried DirectorySecurity.GetAccessRules to find out if they have access to the directory, but that didn't tell me if they had access to the share.

I have tried using [NetShareGetInfo](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsadsi/archive/2012/03/30/to-read-shared-permissions-of-a-server-resource-in-c-using-netsharegetinfo.aspx) but this doesn't seem to work for hidden shares.

Comment: I don't know if this is an option for you, but just trying the operation and catching the error might be the easiest solution in this case. Apart from that: Good question.